# Prometheus settings for Tarantool

Tags: tarantool

Please share an example of valid Prometheus settings to use with Tarantool.
https://github.com/tarantool/metrics/tree/master/metrics/plugins/prometheus

This seems to work, put shows nothing:

```
prometheus = require('metrics.plugins.prometheus')
metrics = require('http.server').new('0.0.0.0', 8080)
router = require('http.router').new({charset = "utf8"})
metrics:set_router(router)
router:route( { path = '/metrics' }, prometheus.collect_http)
metrics:start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
metrics = require('metrics')
metrics.enable_default_metrics()

prometheus = require('metrics.plugins.prometheus')
metrics = require('http.server').new('0.0.0.0', 8080)
router = require('http.router').new({charset = "utf8"})
metrics:set_router(router)
router:route( { path = '/metrics' }, prometheus.collect_http)
metrics:start()
```